# Terraform AWS ALB Module: disable HTTP/2

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-application-load-balancer

Following the instruction for alb module of Terraform https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/alb/aws/latest

I can't understand how to disable HTTP/2
can you help me?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post your Terraform code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the module requirements, the `enable_http2` variable is optional [1] and by default set to `true`. You can change that by adding this variable when calling the module and setting it to `false`:

```
enable_http2 = false
```

---

[1] https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-alb/blob/master/variables.tf#L19-L23

Comment: @Sarah Accepting the answer would be appreciated.